# Which phrase is correct, "dependent on" or "dependent upon"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, prepositions

Which sentence is correct?

> My project is **dependent upon** your project completing.

> My project is **dependent on** your project completing.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/the-influence-of-on-upon.

Answer (score 20):

They are equivalent; *upon* is just a more formal term for *on*, and it is especially used in abstract senses.

The copy of the NOAD I can access on my Mac via the *Dictionary* app reports the following note about the usage of *upon*.

> The preposition *upon* has the same core meaning as the preposition *on*. *Upon* is sometimes more formal than *on*, however, and is preferred in the phrases *once upon a time* and *upon my word*, and in uses such as *row upon row of seats* and *Christmas is almost upon us*.

The same note is readable on [the Lexico website](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/upon).

Answer (score 9):

based on this [NGram, "dependent on" seems slightly ahead](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=%27%20dependent%20on%20%27,%27%20dependent%20upon%20%27&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0)

[image: Ngram of "dependent on" vs. "dependent upon"]

here's the same image with [some smoothing](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=%27%20dependent%20on%20%27,%27%20dependent%20upon%20%27&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=50)

[image: Ngram of "dependent on" vs. "dependent upon" with smoothing=50]