# 'Depend upon' or 'depend on'

Tags: phrases, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which phrase is correct: “dependent on” or “dependent upon”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25662/which-phrase-is-correct-dependent-on-or-dependent-upon)

Is there a difference between the usage of 'depend upon' and 'depend on' or is one considered improper usage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOAD:**

> The preposition ‘upon’ has the same core meaning as the preposition ‘on’.
>   ‘Upon’ is sometimes more formal than ‘on’, however, and is preferred in
>   the phrases: *once upon a time* and *upon my word*, and in uses such as: *row upon row of seats* and *Christmas is almost upon us*.

There is no other difference than that.

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically there is no difference.

Style and usage?  It is one of the "nicer" selections to have to make, as you can choose based on:

a: It is better to your ear,(1)

Or:

b: It is better targeted at your readership,

Or:

c: A combination of a and b.

(1) Italian has a word ("orecchiabile") for which the closest English translation is "*palatable to the ear*".  Given that English is, shall we say, an "illegitimate" language, whose parentage is not strictly defined, I think that we should either steal the word (to add to the list of other words we've stolen), or create one that means the same thing.